# Program maximum Call Stack Exceeded

Tags: javascript

Whenever I press the buttons in my program, it says the maximum call size is exceeded, and I don't know what to do to make my program run.

Here is the code.

```js
function check() {
  var input = document.getElementById("num").value;
  var check = /^[0-9]*$/;
  check.test(input) ? window.alert("You have only entered numeric characters! Please proceed to press one of the other buttons.") : window.alert("Please enter only numbers!");
}

function abs() {
  var abs_input = document.getElementById("num").value;
  document.write("The absolute value of your number is: " + abs(abs_input));
}

function round() {
  var input = document.getElementById("num").value;
  document.write("The value of your number rounded is: " + round(input));
}

function log() {
  var input = document.getElementById("num").value;
  document.write("The natural logarithm of your number is: " + log(input));
}
```

```html
<center>
  <label style="font-size:40px">Please Enter A Number Here:</label>
  <input type="text" id="num" style="font-size:40px">
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="check()" style="font-size:20px">Check</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="abs()" style="font-size:20px">Absolute Value</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="round()" style="font-size:20px">Rounded Value</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="log()" style="font-size:20px">Log Value</button>
  <br />
  <br />
</center>
```

Comment: Its because of endless recursion. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

In your `abs` function, `abs(abs_input)` will call the function again. In it, it will happen again. And again. And again. And again. And... eventually the computer will not be able to remember how many times you called it and from where.

What you probably wanted is to call `Math.abs(abs_input)` inside your `abs()` function - a built-in function, different from your `abs()` one, so you don't get the infinite recursion (a function calling itself till it can't any more).

Same for `round` and `Math.round`, and `log` and `Math.log`.